# Can javascript click a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Is it possible to make javascript click on a div when the div exists in the browser?

For example, the script could refresh a webpage until a div shows up (with content), and than if the div is clickable, let javascript click it (or just follow the link, if there is one).

Comment: add code which you have tried

Comment: I didnt made code yet, i was only wondering if this is possible with js!

Comment: look for a `click()` function in the doc maybe ??   http://api.jquery.com/click/#click

Comment: The website im running the script on is not my own, so i cannot assign the click function to a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jquery . use $(window).load(); function which attach all event after body load all content in web page . see below code  : [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) you can read document of [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/);

working example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmg8tvpe/)

```
 <div id="yourDivId"></div>    

  $(window).load(function () {
    $(document).on('click',"#yourDivId",function () {
         // Some code here
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s possible.

You can add a `click` event handler function using jQuery as mentioned above.

To fire the click event of that div, do

```
$("#mydiv").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct one

```
<div id="mydiv></div>    
$(window).load(function () {
$(document).on('click',"#mydiv",function () {
     // Some code here
 });
});
```

Comment: "refreshing the page until..."  if the div doesn't exists, this will fire nothing