# Auto-click a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, submit, autofill

Here is the code for the button that needs pressed:

```
<div id="ccBtns">
  <input type="button" name="" value="submit" class="startSessionButton submit required">
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using: `document.getElementById('submit').click();`

I am using this code in a plugin called Autofill for chrome.

EDIT: I found that his works
`document.querySelector('input[type=button]').click();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can javascript click a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006288/can-javascript-click-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong becouse you try to click a button with **id** equals to submit.

Your button doesn't have id like that. Try that:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('submit').click();
```